# can we repopulate session again in global file's Session_End event?

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, global-asax

Can we repopulate the session like user info, id, etc. in global.asax file's Session_End event instead of redirecting user to login page so user does not have to login again?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: actually I was being specific about .net
thanks by the way

Comment: Saying "ASP.NET" implies ".NET".

Answer (score 2):

`Session_End` means that session was expired. Default session time to live is 20 minutes. Also session has sliding expiration. So if user won't do any requests in 20 minutes, then this session will be expired and `Session_End` event will be called.

If you need bigger session timeout, you can increase it in web.config like:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="60"  />
</system.web>
```

But repopulate session on `Session_End` event hasn't too much sense for me, as anyway user isn't on site at least for 20 minutes. And each session anyway will be expired, as server needs to free memory used by inactive sessions to process new sessions and don't waste memory with old one.

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of ways of handling this. When Session_End occurs - the session has ended. I have code at the top of all my pages (or on a master page) that checks to see if the session has gone. I tend to do things like store 2 GUIDs against a user and return them both when a user logs in. I stick one in a cookie on the user's box and the other in a hidden field (again, preferably in a master page or user control that appears on every page). If the session times out I retrieve one GUID from the cookie, the other from the hidden field, and use both of them to go back to the database, retrieve the user's details and repopulate the session.

On sites where users are logged in all day - I refresh the session every 15 minutes with javascript. Thousands of users on a pretty low end server environment - never had any problems.